# Conversion of probabilities to rate

Tags: probability, data-transformation, markov-process

I need to convert this matrix of weekly probabilities to annual probabilities. However, when converting it into annual rates and transforming them into probabilities does not give reasonable values ​​(they are all equal to 1), do you have any idea how to do it?

[image]

Comment: You may want to give a little more information. This looks like a Markov process, what do you mean by weekly probabilities and annual probabilities?

Comment: Thanks
This probabilities were extracted from a past paper,  and were used to built a Markov process. Each probability are wekly probabilities between states. But, I need to transform this weekly probabilities to anual probabilities. I try to transform each one in rates, mutiply by 52 to obtain anual rates, and then transform this anual rate to probabilities, but I obtein wrong values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your monthly probabilities mean.

If it's the probability of at least one 'incident' of a particular
kind within a month, and if the number $X$ of incidents is Poisson distributed
then, for example,  $$1 - 0.274 = P(X =0) = e^{-\lambda},$$ where $\lambda$ is the monthly rate and $\lambda_{12} = 12\lambda$ would be the yearly rate.

Then $\lambda_{12} = -12\ln(1-.274) = 2,84.$ [Computation in R, where `log` is $\ln.]$

```
-12*log(1-.274)
[1] 3.842463
```

Then the probability of at least one 'incident' within a year would be
$1 - e^{\lambda_{12}} = 0.9786,$

```
1-exp(-3.8425)
[1] 0.9785601
```

Moreover, the probability of $12$ or more 'incidents' in a year
would be 0.00065.  (In R, `ppois` is a Poisson CDF.)

```
lam.12 = -12*log(1-.274)
1 - ppois(11, lam.12)
[1] 0.0006509606
```

Plots of Monthly and Yearly Poisson distributions are shown below.

[image]

That's a lot of assumptions. If they're uselessly wrong, maybe you can
edit your question to clarify what your data entries really do mean.

Comment: Thanks
This probabilities were extracted from a past paper,  and were used to built a Markov process. Each probability are wekly probabilities between states. But, I need to transform this weekly probabilities to anual probabilities. I try to transform each one in rates, mutiply by 52 to obtain anual rates, and then transform this anual rate to probabilities, but I obtein wrong values.

Comment: I think you are confusing properties of rates and probabilities. You can multiply weekly rate to yearly rate by multiplying by 52, but that doesn't work for probabilities. (**Couldn't possibly work**; you could get probabilities greater than 1 that way!)

Comment: It is clear. I can obtain a yearly rate (from weekly rate), and I do. The question is when I obtain the yearly rate, and I transform this yearly rate to probability( P(X<t)=1-exp(- r * t) ), I obtain some wrong values.